# How to display duplicate count from two tables where one column duplicate value separate in two column from each table

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all I want to thank you all members of this community for posting very helpful answers. I am using this kind of plateform first so I am sorry for my grammatical mistakes and if it is a silly question.

I am having a use case as given in below image link.
[Having two tables 1. is Office_1 and 2. is Office_2 and want the Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUZAS.jpg)

For this use case I am able to get Output separately only from one table using below query

First query is for one table (Office_1)

`select EID as EID,sum(case when OP like 'come' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Office_1 Come COUNT',sum(case when OP like 'go' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Office_1 Go COUNT' from Office_1 where DATE >= '2022-01-16' AND DATE <= '2022-01-18' group by UID;`

Second query is for another table (Office_2)

`select EID as EID,sum(case when OP like 'come' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Office_2 Come COUNT',sum(case when OP like 'go' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Office_2 Go COUNT' from Office_2 where DATE >= '2022-01-16' AND DATE <= '2022-01-18' group by UID;`

But I want that UID must be selected from first table and output must be combined to display. Please help me in this use case. How to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
select* from(select EID as EID,sum(case when OP like 'come' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Office_1 Come COUNT',sum(case when OP like 'go' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Office_1 Go COUNT',date as dt from Office_1 

union

select EID as EID,sum(case when OP like 'come' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Office_2 Come COUNT',sum(case when OP like 'go' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Office_2 Go COUNT',date as dt from Office_2)

where dt >= '2022-01-16' AND DATE <= '2022-01-18' group by UID;
```

Please refer here for more information about union select https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html